# UIImagePickerController continue to select image

Tags: iphone

I know UIImagePickerController can only select one image from library each time. When user select one image, UIPickerController will disappear. But I noticed the app "Good Reader", when it launchs UIImagePickerController, after user choose one image, it prompt a small window says "processing the image", but UIImagePickerController does not dissappear which will let the user continue to choose other images.

I do not know how this can be realized?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that you just dont call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` until you are doing processing.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
                didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    // do your magic here, and display processing UI

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```